# Cannot install firebase-admin package on PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pip, firebase-admin

I cannot install firebase-admin on PyCharm and make it work. I have already installed firebase-admin in the terminal using:

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

Output when I run this code:

```
Requirement already satisfied: firebase-admin in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client>=1.7.8 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from firebase-admin) (2.51.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from firebase-admin) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cachecontrol>=0.12.6 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from firebase-admin) (0.12.11)
Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-storage>=1.37.1 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from firebase-admin) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-firestore>=2.1.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from firebase-admin) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack>=0.5.2 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cachecontrol>=0.12.6->firebase-admin) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cachecontrol>=0.12.6->firebase-admin) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.56.2 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (1.56.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf<4.0.0dev,>=3.15.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (3.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0dev,>=1.33.2 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (1.46.3)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio-status<2.0dev,>=1.33.2 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (1.46.3)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<1dev,>=0.15.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.7.8->firebase-admin) (0.20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-httplib2>=0.1.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.7.8->firebase-admin) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: uritemplate<5,>=3.0.1 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.7.8->firebase-admin) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-cloud-core<3.0.0dev,>=1.4.1 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-cloud-firestore>=2.1.0->firebase-admin) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: proto-plus<2.0.0dev,>=1.20.5 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-cloud-firestore>=2.1.0->firebase-admin) (1.20.6)
Requirement already satisfied: google-resumable-media>=2.3.2 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-cloud-storage>=1.37.1->firebase-admin) (2.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: google-crc32c<2.0dev,>=1.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from google-resumable-media>=2.3.2->google-cloud-storage>=1.37.1->firebase-admin) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.3,<4,>=2.4.2 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from httplib2<1dev,>=0.15.0->google-api-python-client>=1.7.8->firebase-admin) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->cachecontrol>=0.12.6->firebase-admin) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->cachecontrol>=0.12.6->firebase-admin) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->cachecontrol>=0.12.6->firebase-admin) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests->cachecontrol>=0.12.6->firebase-admin) (2.0.11)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\xubil\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1->firebase-admin) (0.4.8)
```

However, when I go into my settings and then to project interpreter, firebase-admin is not shown.
[Check Project Interpreter here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EItc8.png)

I tried installing the package through the project interpreter many times, but errors keep occurring; Here is the whole Command Output: https://textdoc.co/G6KfVxvReMFbN8c2

As you can see, [the package is still not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDGuH.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED!!!!**

Pycharm seems to have chosen the `Mingw` interpreter instead of the python interpreter at `C:\Users\[your user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310.`

Change the interpreter to the right one and it should work.

`File>>Settings>>Project>>Project Interpreter>>Python Interpreter, then select the right interpreter or add the path to it.`